# Retrieve object with a key in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have following object, and if I want to retrieve only soccer, then I put soccer as follows, 
`sports['soccer']` does not bring it.

I wonder what I am missing here?

```
sports = [] ; 

sports = [{
    "soccer": {
        "type": "foot",
        "player": 11
    },
    "basketball": {
        "type": "hand",
        "player": 5
    }
}]
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you have an array with a single object? Will the array have multiple objects in your actual code?

Comment: `sports[0].soccer`

Comment: without hardcoded, is there a way to iterate through and find the object with the given key which is soccer in my case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 3):

Your current code creates an array with a single object. One solution is to just create an object instead:

```
sports = {
    "soccer": {
        "type": "foot",
        "player": 11
    },
    "basketball": {
        "type": "hand",
        "player": 5
    }
}
```

Now you can use `sports.soccer` or `sports['soccer']` to access the soccer data.

If you really want an array of objects, you first need to subscript the array to get the first object:

```
sports[0].soccer
```

or

```
sports[0]['soccer']
```

Comment: Is there a way to keep as an array then find the corresponding object with a given key which is soccer.

Comment: @hotspring If you want to get the object by a key as a variable, you can do `sports[0][key]`.

Answer (score 0):

`var sports` is an array with objects inside.

If you set it up like this:

```
sports = [] ; 

sports = {
   "soccer": {
       "type": "foot",
       "player": 11
   },
   "basketball": {
      "type": "hand",
      "player": 5
   }
}
```

then you will be able to call `sports['soccer']` or even `sports.soccer`.

Alternately, if you need it to remain an array, then you'll need to do more work.
Something like this should do the trick.

```
for(i=0; i < sports.length; i++) {
  if("soccer" in sports[i]){
    console.log(sports[i].soccer.type);
    console.log(sports[i].soccer.player);
  }
}
```

The console.logs represent whatever you want to do with the values

Answer (score 0):

I think you really need to reiterate the basics of javascript a bit.

In JS we can create data structures on the fly with literal syntax. For example:

```js
let normalArr = new Array();
let literalArr = [];

let normalObj = new Object();
let literalObj = {};
```

When you create arrays and objects with literal syntax you can initialize arrays with elements and object with properties on the fly. This is what exactly happened in your example:

```
sports = [{
    "soccer": {
        "type": "foot",
        "player": 11
    },
    "basketball": {
        "type": "hand",
        "player": 5
    }
}];
```

The code can be broken down in the following way:

1. You created an array which was stored in the sports variable using the array literal syntax (created an array on the fly).
2. You created 1 element of the array with the object literal syntax (creating an object on the fly)
3. This object (located inside the array) has 2 properties, soccer and basketball which are also object created with object literal syntax.

To access one of there objects you need to do the following:

```js
const sports = [{
    "soccer": {
        "type": "foot",
        "player": 11
    },
    "basketball": {
        "type": "hand",
        "player": 5
    }
}];

// accessing the first element of the sports array
console.log(sports[0].soccer);
console.log(sports[0].basketball);
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you have an array of objects, not a single object. You can use the `find()` method to find the element that has the `soccer` property, and then access that property.

```
var soccer = sports.find(s => 'soccer' in s)['soccer'];
```